# QGraphicsTextItem inheritance. Strange behaviour

Tags: qt, qgraphicstextitem

I created a class, inherited from `QGraphicsTextItem`. Object of this class must be movable and must send signal when MouseButton is up.

```
class MyTextItem: public QObject, public QGraphicsTextItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyTextItem(QObject* Object, QString str1): QGraphicsTextItem(str1), mRef(Object){}
    virtual void mouseReleaseEvent (QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent* event);
    QObject* mRef;
signals:
    void sendSignal(int x, int y);
```

Then I create object:

```
MyTextItem* label = new MyTextItem(NULL, "QwertyuiopAsdfghjkl");
label->setPos(p);
label->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable, true);
```

And all is OK. But, when I add:

```
QFont f;
f.setBold(false);
f.setItalic(false);
f.setPixelSize(16);
f.setFamily("Arial");
f.setLetterSpacing(QFont::AbsoluteSpacing, 0.1);
label->setFont(f);
//
scene()->addItem(label);
```

My test became cutted off (font is bigger, but width of object is without changes)! Why?. When I use `QGraphicsTextItem` instead of `MyTextItem` all is fine.

How to update item size after font increasing?
Thank you!

[image]
[image]

Comment: If i delete inheritance from QObject - all shows correct.. But i cant send signal without it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow! A wrote

```
class PolygonLabel: public QGraphicsTextItem, public QObject
```

instead of

```
class PolygonLabel: public QObject, public QGraphicsTextItem
```

and problem was done!

Answer (score 0):

To start with, rather than the multiple inhertance, inherit from `QGraphicsObject`. The `QGraphicsObject` class provides a base class for all graphics items that require signals, slots and properties.

The reason your text is cut off may also be due to the fact that you've not overridden the `boundingRect` function, which returns the bounding rectangle of the area you're drawing in. See [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#boundingRect).